# How does one move control parameters from asp controls to the C# codebehind file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I'm in the process of cleaning up a bunch of legacy code in a ASP.NET webapp, and there's a group of asp control parameters that I would like to move to the C# codebehind file, but I keep getting an error when I try to add the control parameter only in the C# file.

This is what I'm trying to move:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource" runat="server">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbProvider" DefaultValue="%" Name="provider" 
            PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In the codebehind I'm attempting to replicate that code as this:

```
        SqlDataSource ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
        ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource.ConnectionString = DatabaseConnectionString;
        ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource.SelectCommand = "dbo.SearchProvider";
        ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
        ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource.Selected += dsProviderSearch_Selected;

        ControlParameter ProviderControlParameter = new ControlParameter();
        ProviderControlParameter.ControlID = "tbProvider";
        ProviderControlParameter.Name = "provider";
        ProviderControlParameter.DefaultValue = "%";
        ProviderControlParameter.PropertyName = "Text";

        ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(ProviderControlParameter);
```

That code is then used as the datasource for a gridview that exists on the ascx file using this code:

```
        ProviderSearchGridView.DataSource = ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource;

        ProviderSearchGridView.DataBind();
```

With the select parameter removed from the asp file, and using only the C# codebehind, I get this error as soon as I attempt to databind ProviderSearchGridView:

```
Additional information: The SqlDataSource control '' does not have a naming container.  Ensure that the control is added to the page before calling DataBind.
```

I do not get that error when the control parameter is defined in the ascx file and not defined in the C# file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource  is going out of scope before you DataBind()? Try using a member variable as an SqlDataSource instead of a local variable.

Comment: Does `ProviderSearchGridView` still have a `DataSourceID` defined?

Comment: @Malk, negative, it's an empty string.

Comment: @Mausimo I'm checking into scope and name collision issues, but it doesn't look like it's going out of scope.

Comment: Remove the attribute entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete code that I used to solve my problem:

```
    protected void SearchButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet tProviderData = SelectProviderWithParameter();
            cProviderSearchGridView.DataSource = tProviderData;

            cProviderSearchGridView.Visible = true;
            cProviderSearchGridView.DataBind();

            if (cProviderSearchGridView.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                cSearchMessageLabel.Text = "No results found. Please modify your search and try again.";
                cSearchMessageLabel.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cSearchMessageLabel.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private DataSet SelectProviderWithParameter()
    {
        DataSet tProviderData = new DataSet();

        string tProviderTextboxContent = tbProvider.Text.Trim();
        string tCityDropDownSelection = cCityDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();
        string tPracticeGroupDropDownSelection = cProviderDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();
        string tSpecialtyDropDownSelection = cSpecialtyDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();
        string tZipTextboxContent = tbZip.Text.Trim();
        string tProviderContractAreaDropDownSelection = cContractAreaDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();

        using (SqlConnection tProviderConnection = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter tProviderAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                try
                {
                    tProviderConnection.Open();

                    SqlCommand tProviderSearch = new SqlCommand("dbo.SearchProvider", tProviderConnection);
                    tProviderSearch.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    tProviderSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("Provider", tProviderTextboxContent);
                    tProviderSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProviderCity", tCityDropDownSelection);
                    tProviderSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProviderPracticeGroup", tPracticeGroupDropDownSelection);
                    tProviderSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProviderSpecialty", tSpecialtyDropDownSelection);
                    tProviderSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProviderZipCode", tZipTextboxContent);
                    tProviderSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProviderContractArea", tProviderTextboxContent);

                    tProviderAdapter.SelectCommand = tProviderSearch;
                    tProviderAdapter.Fill(tProviderData);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }

        return tProviderData;
    }
```

The important part for the problem that I was trying to solve are these lines:

```
tProviderSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("Provider", tProviderTextboxContent);
tProviderSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProviderCity", tCityDropDownSelection);
tProviderSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProviderPracticeGroup", tPracticeGroupDropDownSelection);
tProviderSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProviderSpecialty", tSpecialtyDropDownSelection);
tProviderSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProviderZipCode", tZipTextboxContent);
tProviderSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProviderContractArea", tProviderTextboxContent);
```

Once the SqlCommand object is constructed, then its Parameters property can be accessed and parameters added before the adapter executes the search. In my code I just pulled the values directly from the form fields for the query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource.ID = "ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource";
```

after

```
SqlDataSource ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
```

So it should look like:

```
SqlDataSource ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource.ID = "ProviderSearchGridViewDataSource";
```

Here you might find [ASP.NET - Programatically Adding SqlDataSource and GridView (Part 1)](http://learningpcs.blogspot.com/2010/09/aspnet-programatically-adding_15.html) that explains similar to what you doing.